# Infowindow with information from other table

Tags: sql, infowindow, cartodb

I want to add an infowindow to on of my layers. In this infowindow I want to show information from another layer (it also exist as a table in my cartodb account).

```
var sublayerVerbindungen = layer.getSubLayer(1);
sublayerVerbindungen.hide();
sublayerVerbindungen.setInteractivity('cartodb_id, a_route, the_geom, a_route_info');
sublayerVerbindungen.setInteraction(true);

var sublayerA=layer.createSubLayer({
    sql: "SELECT * FROM verbindungen WHERE a_route=1",
    cartocss: '#verbindungen {line-color: #33a02c;}'
});
```

So I want to add my infowindow to the layer sublayerA which has the information from sublayerVerbindungen.
I have tried to use this:

```
cdb.vis.Vis.addInfowindow(map, sublayerVerbindungen, ['a_route_info']);
```

But its not working.